# MySQL vs Firebird vs SQLite

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, firebird

We will implement a company based ( not open source ) software and I really cannot choose which one I am going to work with. I can see the differences between all of them 
[here](http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/compare/13-30-53/Firebird-vs-MySQL-vs-SQLite)
but I need more specific information, like is really MySql not free for not open source projects ([based on this blog](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/firebird_gain_mysql.html)) or how about their comparison in deployment?

EDIT :  I need to expand my question. We are just implementing an API to our existing project. This will be used as a standalone program but it is an embedded system project so the deployement is really really important. I know that SQLite is really easy to deploy but I can see there are a few disadvantages. Can you please tell me which one can be better used according to this situation ?

Thank you all

Comment: @mehmetozer: do you need an embedded engine? If not you should definitely consider PostgreSQL as well.

Comment: but who uses mysql as an embedded database? :-)

Comment: You can also take a look for IBM DB2 Express-C. But the free edition will use only two CPU cores and 2GB of RAM, but has no limit on number of users or on database size. For most projects, it is sufficient. You can get other editons and support as you need.

Comment: P.S.: I use Postgres but sometimes a IBM-Logo somewhere looks beneficial ;)

Comment: To improve the question (and to get the more specific information you seek), you should clarify what your requirements are. Currently this question reads like "I want to buy a car, which one should I get?".

Comment: As long as it is build by your company for internal use within that company, you need not bother with wether it's open source or not. You're not distributing the software, so GPL (for MySQL) does not apply.

Comment: +1 for the comparison link. The best I had ever seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't answer for all of them, but SQLite is entirely free to use in any application at all. It's explicitly been put in the [Public Domain](http://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html); you can get a license if you insist, but you're just getting what you have total right to anyway. For deployment, SQLite is certainly deployed in many places (inside many browsers, many smartphones, etc.) so it's definitely production-quality, but you do need to be in a position  to be able to work with a native code library (SQLite's written in C, and compiles to a library); as it happens, that rules it out of my current projects…

Answer (score 11):

For firebird this is here http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/about-firebird/

> Firebird is a relational database offering many ANSI SQL standard
>   features that runs on Linux, Windows, and a variety of Unix platforms.
>   Firebird offers excellent concurrency, high performance, and powerful
>   language support for stored procedures and triggers. It has been used
>   in production systems, under a variety of names, since 1981.
>
> The Firebird Project is a commercially independent project of C and
>   C++ programmers, technical advisors and supporters developing and
>   enhancing a multi-platform relational database management system based
>   on the source code released by Inprise Corp (now known as Borland
>   Software Corp) on 25 July, 2000.
>
> FREE LIKE A BIRD. Anyone can build a custom version of Firebird, as
>   long as the modifications are made available, under the same IDPL
>   licensing, for others to use and build on.
>
> FREE LIKE FREE BEER. No fees for download, registration, licensing or
>   deployment, even you distribute Firebird as part of your commercial
>   software package.
>
> Firebird's development depends on voluntary funding by people who
>   benefit from using it. Funding options range from donations, through
>   Firebird Foundation memberships to sponsorship commitments.
>
> Choosing Firebird and saving or making money by your choice? Show your
>   appreciation and encouragement by contributing money in proportion to
>   these benefits.